# Getting an OptimisticLockException whilst retrieving records

Tags: java, hibernate

Getting a `OptimisticLockException` while retrieving data from Hibernate call to DB. Is that necessary that this exception occurs only during insert/update/delete ?

Below is the log snippet which popsup.

> <EJB exception occurred during invocation from home or business: com.XXX.quser.DocQCleanupXRefSBean_yy20q_Intf generated exception: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException>

Answer (score 0):

Normally yes. Are you sure, that your transaction does not include any changes, I am quite sure that it does. You might have manipulated managed entities without knowing. So try to find out in what bound the transaction is set. Do this by looking at the TransactionAttribute of the current method and its caller and their callers, ... 
Perhaps it could help to post the complete stacktrace of this exception.